# How to alternate between bold and regular font in System.Drawing

Tags: c#

I am using the System.Drawing tools to create a graphic. The graphic has a lot of text labels in it.

I create the font:

```
var font = new Font("Verdana", 10);
```

and then, for each label, make the text bold, or not using this:

```
font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold);
font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

I want to store all the text for the labels in a database along with font size and whether it is to be bold or not.

Say I return a list of values from a database like, for example:

10, bold

12, regular

10, bold,

14, bold

10, regular

and put those values in a list object with properties of myfontSize and myfontStyle and loop through the list ... what is the best way to modify my System.Drawing font to reflect the changes in Font Size and Font Weight required in each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough information to answer this question fully. However, without going into much detail in terms of how you get the list, if you have a list of font sizes/style then you would just iterate the collection and create a new font object e.g.

```
var fontCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
fontCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(10, "Bold"));
fontCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(12, "Regular"));
fontCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(14, "Bold"));
foreach (var item in fontCollection)
{
    var font = new Font("Verdana", item.Key, (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), item.Value));
    // use font
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what value would be KeyValuePair FontStyle. Obviously, the KeyValuePair int will be 10 or 12 or 14 but if the database returns a string 'bold' or 'regular' - how do I convert this to FontStyle? In your example, what, exactly would item.value contain?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse if the strings are *exactly* the same as the value in the `FontStyle` enum you can parse them straight to that particular type from a string e.g. `(FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), "Bold")`, otherwise you would need to map them manually. Like I said in my answer, you haven't provided enough information to fully answer the question so I am making a few assumptions.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse I have updated my answer to show a working example.

Comment: That's what I was after. Thank you very much.